# Change spelling check language for a Document in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, language, spell-check, microsoft-word-2010

Usually I use `Microsoft Word 2010` to write English documents

Now I'm editing a document of another language, and want to change the spelling check language of this document

This change should not affect other documents (means does not saved by default) so I can work with English documents in the future

Any clue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In Word 2010:

1. Select the text you want to affect. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all the text in the document.
2. **Review** tab > **Language** group > **Language** button > **Set Proofing Language**
3. In the **Language** dialog, select the language you want to use for spell checking.

In Word 2007, **Review** tab > **Proofing** group > **Set Language** will accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of selecting all the text, you can change the language for a specific style. Most styles are based on *Normal*, so you usually only need to change the *Normal* style.

In the Home ribbon, right-click on the *Normal* style and click *Modify*. Then click *Format* -> *Language*, and select the language. A blog post with screenshots is also available [here](http://soundripple.com/2009/10/21/word-2007-document-language-change/).

This should also affect headers and footers.

This works in Office 2007 and 2010. In earlier versions it is also possible, but the process is slightly different.

Comment: This answer is a better way than selecting all the text; I wrote a blog posting on this [here](http://soundripple.com/2009/10/21/word-2007-document-language-change) that screenshots it.

Comment: This works unless you have a style which adds language. I had a table style which set the language to French. Finally the only thing that worked for me was from http://www.wordbanter.com/showpost.php?s=54e632e47b4c5b4fe7bfd07895ef9588&p=293264&postcount=10 is to use a simple macro:

`ActiveDocument.Styles("Table Grid").LanguageID = wdEnglishUS`

Answer (score 2):

The language is determine by the paragraphs language setting (i.e. an English paragraph followed by one in French will each use the right spelling checker).

To change the body of the document, select all and then change the paragraph language, but this will not update headers, footers and footnotes (this other [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/130379/change-spelling-check-language-for-a-document-in-microsoft-word-2010/130523#130523) for details).

Unless you change template content (or update a style with a language and save that change to the template) other documents will not be affected.

Comment: Can you give more details of changing language of a paragraph?

Comment: @hvtuananh: the accepted answer covers this

Answer (score 1):

In Word 2007 and 2010, the status bar at the bottom left shows the current paragraph language.

To change the whole document select all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) then click on the language to change it.

Comment: I'm using Word 2010

Answer (score 0):

Office usually comes with a set of three languages, e.g. English, Spanish and French for the Canadian version. If the language you want to check is not one of the three languages in your copy of Office, you need to download a [language pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=552d34b8-4f30-4d71-bbc5-f31b726f4a22&displaylang=en).

Comment: Yes, it's in my copy of Office 2010

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom where it says your normal language e.g. English (U.K.)
click on that and it will let you change the language

Answer (score 0):

In case you also come here because you're annoyed by having to change the language for all "track changes" comments individually, there's a shortcut:

1. In Word 2011 on Mac, you can choose View>Sidebar>Reviewing Pane. There'll be corresponding ways to access this pane in other versions.
2. Now you can select the text for *all* comments (and headers and footers too) and change their language.

Unfortunately, new comments still use the default language.

Answer (score 0):

in word 2011 mac, you can:

1. select all the text (`command` + `a`)
2. then from the menu go to `Tools` -> `language`
3. in the newly opened window, click on English (or any other language you want)