# Set proofing language for selected text in word

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I have many footnotes that are in MLA format as references. Word's spell/grammar checker complains about the text.

I know that I can disable this if I can figure out how to set the language of that text to `no language` but I can only figure out how to do that for the whole document, not just the selected text.

Is there a way to do this?

If not, is there a way to prevent the spell/grammar checker from checking footnotes, or a page range?

Comment: The accepted answer might help: http://superuser.com/questions/130379/change-spelling-check-language-for-a-document-in-microsoft-word-2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [phenry](https://superuser.com/users/1531/phenry)

> In Word 2010:
>
> 1. Select the text you want to affect. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all the text in the document.
> 2. **Review** tab > **Language** group > **Language** button > **Set Proofing Language**
> 3. In the **Language** dialog, select the language you want to use for spell checking.
>
> In Word 2007, **Review** tab > **Proofing** group > **Set Language** will accomplish the same thing.